# How to open a webpage within a BlackBerry application?

Tags: browser, blackberry

I need to open a webpage from a BlackBerry application. I don't want to use a hyperlink so that users have to navigate to the blackberry browser application.
So, I basically need a full screen where the content of that particular page can be loaded just like a browser.
Is weblinks the answer to what I need or do I need to just invoke a browser session?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For BlackBerry applications you can use

```
   BrowserSession session = Browser.getDefaultSession();
   session.displayPage(url);
```

It will automatically open the browser with the given url. It's basically invoking the browser in your application context, so pressing the back button will take the user back to your application.